# Case With Having

Tags: sql, case

I have Plant, Material, Movement type and Date.

My requirement is I want the MAX date in Material and Plant combination, with Movement type condition

First I need MAX date in Material and Plant combination, where Movement type is 602 , if 602 is null then 601, if 601 is null then 102, if 102 is null then 101 if 101 also is null then other Movement types.

For this I used below code in derived table in IDT but I am not able to get the correct results:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
  Table__1."0PLANT",
  Table__1."0MATERIAL",
  Max(Table__1."0PSTNG_DATE") as Last_Sales_Date
FROM
  "NM1"."PUBLIC"."IZDSO_DMR"  Table__1
  Where
      CASE 
        WHEN (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=602) THEN (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=602)
        WHEN (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=602) IS NULL THEN (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=601)
        ELSE
         (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=601) END
   Group By
     Table__1."0MATERIAL",
     Table__1."0PLANT"
```

I tried only for 602, 601 Movement types only

Please help me to get the correct result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To format a code block, you need not add linebreaks.  Highlight the code block and click the `{}` toolbar button in the editor, or `ctl-k`. Doing so will add a preceding linebreak and indent each line 4 spaces as code.  If appropriately tagged, this also forces syntax highlighting.

Comment: Move the CASE in the MAX function.

Answer (score 0):

This is your `where` clause:

```
Where (CASE WHEN (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=602) THEN (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=602)
            WHEN (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=602) IS NULL THEN (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=601)
            ELSE (Table__1."0MOVETYPE"=601)
      END)
```

This will actually work with some SQL engines, because a comparison is turned into a number.  However, I don't think this is what you want.  You are looking to prioritize the `max()` value, based on the `0MoveType` column.

```
SELECT "0PLANT", "0MATERIAL",
       (case when sum(case when "0MOVETYPE" = 602 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when "0MOVETYPE" = 602 then "0PSTNG_DATE" end)
             when sum(case when "0MOVETYPE" = 601 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when "0MOVETYPE" = 601 then "0PSTNG_DATE" end)
             when sum(case when "0MOVETYPE" = 102 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when "0MOVETYPE" = 102 then "0PSTNG_DATE" end)
             when sum(case when "0MOVETYPE" = 101 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when "0MOVETYPE" = 101 then "0PSTNG_DATE" end)
        end) as Last_Sales_Date
\FROM "NM1"."PUBLIC"."IZDSO_DMR"  Table__1
Group By "0MATERIAL", "0PLANT";
```

This returns the last sales date for "602" if any are present.  If none are present, then it returns the last sales date of "601".  If neither "601" nor "602" are present, then it goes to "102" and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, The code which you given is working perfectly. I would like to select the Movement type also, if I add the Movement type in group by getting the wrong result, how can I overcome this.